# Wpf assignment - Auction sale

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Can some one help me with school assignment. I am total beginner in this and there is lot of things i don't understand. I am going in school now to learn about programming but it is going very slow for me and professor gave us assignment to do but unfortunately i don't know how to solve it. Can someone help me? Please.

Assignment is following:

### "Auction sale"

Create WPF application for auction sale which has following:
-application includes system for managing users realized trough data base. It has to have at least two users(administrator and ordinary user).
-Auctions is taking data from data base
-in main window of auction sale it is showing all products which are at the moment on auction. For every product it shows data about price, last offer and last bidder.
-User who is not login has right to watch all about auction but has no right to bid.
-normal user has right only to bid for price
-administrator has right to input new product and deleting existing ones. Everything when new product is input it has to be put his starting price, name and other information.

### How Auction should work:

That moment when product is entered, auction for that product is starting and count down is starting. Every auction has 2 minutes time to finish. As long as users are putting bids, time of auction is restarting to beginning and gets additional 2 minutes. When user gives bid for product, price for product is increasing every dollar . When auction is over, last user who put bid is mark as winner and auction is closing and it stops to be available for other users.

I have try to create some of the mine code, but i am getting different errors.

Some of the error messages but there is more:'AukcijskaProdaja.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'button1_Click' and no extension method 'button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'AukcijskaProdaja.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?);The name 'conn' does not exist in the current context    c:\users\denis\documents\visual studio; The type or namespace name 'AukcijaDataSet' does not exist in the namespace 'AukcijskaProdaja' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

### xaml:

```xml
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <my:AukcijaDataSet x:Key="aukcijaDataSet" />
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="aukcija_bazeViewSource" Source="{Binding        Path=Aukcija_baze, Source={StaticResource aukcijaDataSet}}" />
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="136"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="78,22,0,0" Name="aukcija_bazeDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="391">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="aukcijaIdColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=AukcijaId}" Header="Aukcija Id" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="artikalNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ArtikalName}" Header="Artikal Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cijenaColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Cijena}" Header="Cijena" Width="SizeToHeader" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Label Content="AukcijaId" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,268,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" />
    <Label Content="ArtikalName" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,267,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,240,0,0" Name="AukcijaId" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" DataContext="{Binding Path=aukcijaIdColumn}" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,240,0,0" Name="ArtikalName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" DataContext="{Binding Path=artikalNameColumn}"/>
    <Button Content="Ponuda" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,240,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Label Content="Vrijeme" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="378,240,0,148" Name="label4" Width="81" />
    <Label Content="Unesi ponudu" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,206,0,0" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" />
    <ListBox Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,153,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="391" />
</Grid>
```

### C#:

```
namespace AukcijskaProdaja
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AukcijskaProdaja.AukcijaDataSet aukcijaDataSet = ((AukcijskaProdaja.AukcijaDataSet)(this.FindResource("aukcijaDataSet")));
        // Load data into the table Aukcija_baze. You can modify this code as needed.
        AukcijskaProdaja.AukcijaDataSetTableAdapters.Aukcija_bazeTableAdapter aukcijaDataSetAukcija_bazeTableAdapter = new AukcijskaProdaja.AukcijaDataSetTableAdapters.Aukcija_bazeTableAdapter();
        aukcijaDataSetAukcija_bazeTableAdapter.Fill(aukcijaDataSet.Aukcija_baze);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource aukcija_bazeViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("aukcija_bazeViewSource")));
        aukcija_bazeViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    public void BindMyData()
    {
        try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Aukcija_baze", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        da.Fill(ds);
        aukcija_bazeDataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    BindMyData();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Aukcija_baze VALUES(" + AukcijaId.Text + ",'" + ArtikalName.Text + "',", conn);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            BindMyData();
        }

        {
            DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();

        }

    }
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add some info: What errors did you have? Your questions do not allow for a good answer. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for what a good question looks like

Comment: Hi Sascha, i edit above for what errors are appearing, but i can see that my code is not good at all and needs to be rewrite obviously. Try also maybe copy paste my code in Visual Studio and will see all errors.

Comment: @Ronin so our job is re-write your code and correct your program ? did you try to search for those errors in Google before asking a question?

Comment: +1, I agree that some more research could be in order, but it is a clear question with a posted attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you haven't included all the code, but I will point out the errors I see:

1. In "BindMyData" and your click handler, you use the "conn" variable. This variable is never declared. In general, SqlConnections should be short lived, so it should probably be declared inside each function that uses it, instead of at the class level. Regardless, you need to declare it at some scope where those functions can see it.
2. In Window_Loaded, there is a variable of type AukcijaDataSet, which has no code posted. Given that I don't think you intended to rewrite the data set class, this (and the other similar lines, like AukcijaDataSetTableAdapters) should use the standard .NET names (like DataSet). If you DID intend to rewrite these classes, make sure you have a using statement for the namespace and a reference in your project if these are in an external library.
3. You are setting the "DataContext" properties of your text boxes, and binding the DataGrid to the entire window data context. Assuming your CollectionViewSource binding works (which I seriously doubt, you need a proper view model in there), you would use a static resource binding instead. The text boxes should have their text property bound to a property of the view model, not have their Data Context set.

Your column bindings actually look ok at first glance, and you are definitely on the right track in general. It does need a lot of clean-up though, and a proper MVVM setup would help.

You should also try to google the errors as the comments noted. Anytime you see a "can't find" or "does not exist" type error, it means you are missing a decleration (in case of a variable) or a missing class definition or reference (if it is on a type name).